# How can I load angularjs 1.* ngRoute with webpack 4.*?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-routing, webpack-4

I am trying to set up a basic angularjs + webpack project. I can get it running well as long as i stick to angularjs alone `(ngApp = angular.module('ngApp), [])`). Whenever I try to take the step to add some angular extension (`ngApp = angular.module('ngApp), ['ngRoute']`) something just doesn't work. I'm fairly certain the problem is with the loading of the library. I don't want to use bower, i want to use Webpack to run it.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
        print: './src/print.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Webpack Starter App',
            template: './src/templates/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    'angular-router-loader',
                    'babel-loader'
                ]
                /* These  2 js loaders were failed attempts at solving this problem*/
            }
        ]
   }
};
```

**ngApp.js**

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import ngRoute from'angular-route';
import './ngApp.controller.root.js';

const ngApp = angular.module('ngApp', [ngRoute]);

ngApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'ngAppRootController',
        templateUrl: './ngApp.view.root.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

ngApp.$inject = [ngRoute];
```

**webconsle error:**

```
angular.js:138 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see error like 'Unknown provider' with random letter like 'e'/'t'/'x', means you need ngInject plugin to let Webpack know which dependency to inject.

Add 'ngInject' right on next line after any dependency injection in Angular file:

```
ngApp.config(function($routeProvider, serviceWhateverYouRequire) {
'ngInject'
$routeProvider.when('/', {  bla-bla-bla
```

or

```
ngApp.config(['$routeProvider', 'serviceWhateverYouRequire', function($routeProvider, serviceWhateverYouRequire) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {  bla-bla-bla
```

We use these libraries for devDependencies with webpack@4.12.0

```
"ng-annotate-loader": "0.1.0",
"ng-annotate-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
"ts-ng-annotate-loader": "^0.2.1"
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I was missing something in the setup connection the two.